# 変数にJSON文字列が入ってる状態でコマンドの引数に渡したい

Tags: json, bash

特定のセキュリティグループについてるインバウンドルールを全て削除したい
（正確には置き換えたいのでそのためにまず削除したい）

```
OLD_RULES=`aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq '.SecurityGroups[] | select(.GroupName=="xxxxx") | .IpPermissions'`

aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress \
--group-name xxxxx \
--ip-permissions $OLD_RULES
```

上記のようなスクリプトを書いたのですが文法エラーになってしまいます
$OLD_RULES の中身を１つの引数として渡すにはどう書けばいいのでしょうか

```
aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress \
--group-name xxxxx \
--ip-permissions '{...}'
```

のようにJSONの中身を直接書けば実行できますが

```
aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress \
--group-name xxxxx \
--ip-permissions '$OLD_RULES'
```

と書いてしまうと当然変数が展開されません

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$OLD_RULESを二重引用符で囲んではいかがでしょうか。一重引用符`'`とは異なり、変数の内容を展開してくれます。

```
--ip-permissions "$OLD_RULES"
```

---

```
--ip-permissions $OLD_RULES
```

では、$OLD_RULESに空白が含まれていると、空白までの文字列が`--ip-permissions`に渡されてしまいます。

```
--ip-permissions '$OLD_RULES'
```

では、質問にも書かれているとおり、`$OLD_RULES`という文字列そのもが`--ip-permissions`に渡されてしまい、変数の内容が展開されません。

Comment: うまく行きました！